# How to limit the anger of an unwilling person?

Tags: science-fiction, humans, chemistry, psychology

In my world, people get stronger, faster, and more durable the angrier they are. There is no upper limit to strength. Therefore, in order to limit the strength of an opponent an attacker must limit their opponent's anger. I am looking for an effective way to prevent or mitigate anger. This should be chemical.

Question: How can I reduce or eliminate the anger of an unwilling human.

- Assume that we are dealing with humans
- Assume that there is antagonism or conflict between us.
- Assume that this must be delivered in 1-5 doses
- Assume that the target is in the already partly angry, but is not so angry as to be impenetrable
- Assume that the public dispersal of aerosols is not priority

*Note: it is true that it would be enough for the opponent's anger to be less than the attacker's. However, I believe it isn't practical to quantify "how angry" the attacker is. Assume for the purpose of this question that the attacker's anger isn't relevant.*

Finally, please note that I believe this question is asking for an [on-topic finite list of things.](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6130/catalog-of-question-types/6138#6138) If you believe I have not sufficiently limited my question in that regard, please explain why in comments so I can adjust the question.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140142/discussion-on-question-by-ryan-how-to-limit-the-anger-of-an-unwilling-person).

Comment: You might look into painting your uniform or shield pink. Has been shown to have a calming effect. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker-Miller_pink

Comment: @FlaStorm32 Note that while it "has been shown", it was in one uncontrolled experiment and other experiments did not replicate the finding. Also, presumably you'd need a few minutes surrounded by the color, and it might not work if the target is already angry

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Fentanyl

If someone's unconscious, they can't be angry.

Now, you do run the risk of killing your opponent, but absolutely flooding their system with a hideously powerful narcotic will definitely make it really hard to be angry.  This is (supposed to be) the mechanism by which the FSB [sedated the occupants of the building during the Moscow Theatre Hostage Crisis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moscow_theater_hostage_crisis).

Any aerosolized or skin-contact narcotic would do the trick, but the more powerful, the more likely it takes effect before they can get their mad on.

If you're really worried about lethal effects, then another option might be:

## Rohypnol

Any benzodiazepine/depressant that can be aerosolized, ideally one that demolishes long-term memory.  How can you stay angry if you can't remember what just happened?

From personal experience, I had a cocktail of such drugs for dental surgery.  Judging from how it felt after the fact, it must have been *painful* at the time.  I remember none of it, and never got overwhelmed by pain during, because at any given moment, I was only enduring the pain of the moment, without any accumulation.

Comment: This could work. Especially since it can be dispersed easily. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: This might work, but I'd be doubly pissed when I come too...

Comment: "at any given moment, I was only enduring the pain of the moment" - uhhh... that doesn't sound right. I imagine you'd have been too spaced out to feel anything (closer to your brain stopping or ignoring the pain signals, rather than feeling the pain and then just forgetting about it).

Comment: @NotThatGuy - I only have the dental surgeon's word on it (until I returned to the waiting room, at which point also my mother) but aside from a topical anaesthetic, I was apparently fully conscious, and left the chair under my own power to return to the waiting room.  All those memories are nonexistent.

Comment: @jdunlop I mean, being conscious and not remembering doesn't mean you felt pain at the time. I've never heard of "only enduring the pain of the moment, without any accumulation" when it comes to pain medication (at least not from anyone with a medical background; a Google search for "pain accumulation" returns no relevant results). But what I have heard of is suppressing pain signals so you feel little to nothing at the time. The goal of pain medication isn't to make you forget, that's just a side effect of making you not feel pain.

Comment: @NotThatGuy - from what the dental surgeon told me, making the memory of the pain go away is _also_ desirable, and wasn't an unavoidable side effect, but part of the purpose of the drug cocktail.  "Pain accumulation" is my own term, but if the only pain you're experiencing is the pain of the moment, that's presumably preferable to having been in pain for a long time.  I know a number of anaesthesiologists, and they're all in favour of keeping patients conscious to the maximal extent, because reduction in consciousness comes with a concomitant danger.

Answer (score 12):

Inhibit Norepinephrine or its production

Norepinephrine is the neurotranmitter for both fear and anger. If its production is limited, or something binds it, preventing it from doing anything, anger is all but impossible. If kept too low, howeverl it will also make concentration difficult and will likely lead to depression.

Comment: I'm actually curious to know if there's a way to do this. Is there a drug on the market that does this? Or a surgical procedure?

Comment: @JBH Google suggests that "Norepinephrine Reuptake Inhibitor" is a populous and familiar category of drug, often prescribed for depression. It also looks like there are quite a few other drugs related to suppression of norepinephrine. (I have a hunch there are very few (or no) surgical options.)

Comment: This answer is really interesting. Blocking the anger hormone is a great idea. Could you maybe give a specific drug that can do this? It would be great if it could be applied to large areas of the body to make it easier to hit an opponent with it.

Comment: @Ryan As I mentioned I am decent at neurochemistry but I know next to nothing about pharmacology, you will need to ask another more specific question, I suggest using the medical tag.

Comment: I believe reuptake inhibitors are taken orally and take days or weeks to have the desired effect. Not much use in a fight!

Comment: @Tom a reuptake inhibitor **increases** the amount of available norepinephrine, by slowing down the transporters that hoover up released neurotransmitter back into the cells (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norepinephrine_reuptake_inhibitor). Your best bet is inhibiting adrenergic receptors with the drugs we currently use for hypertension, alpha and beta blockers, but I’m not aware that these actually reduce aggression in the patients who take them.

Answer (score 9):

## Bullets fired from a gun

One of the symptoms of elevated anger levels is an elevated heart rate. A great way to prevent elevated heart rates is to slow down the heart by poking large holes in the human it is inside of. This will also reduce how angry they are. If you can reduce their heart rate to zero, they will not be angry at all ever again.

> This should be chemical.

The chamber of a gun is really just a high-stress chemistry lab, if you think about it.

> Assume that this must be delivered in 1-5 doses

Most of the time, 1-5 doses of bullets should be enough

> Assume that the target is in the already partly angry, but is not so angry as to be impenetrable

Perfect, then there’s no reason not to shoot them.

If you absolutely have to involve a drug of some kind, dope the bullet with Sarin or VX. That should calm down an entire city block.

Comment: Interesting reframing of the term "Calm".. Well they do say _rest_ in peace right?

Comment: This is an interesting answer. This could apply in a worst case scenario, when someone intends to cause vast devastation and there is no other choice but to kill them. However, it wouldn't be the first solution, since it is lethal.

Comment: @Ryan Any "non-lethal" drug that works fast enough to make a difference in this situation is likely nearly as dangerous as being shot. There's a reason why anesthesiology is a complex and precise field. Dosage is a vital thing, and spray-and-pray drugging is going to absolutely kill people.

Comment: @DanielB ok, that makes sense. In the Moscow theater crisis many people died from the gas. I guess that lethal means are what would work...

Comment: In today's news, a man _calmed down_ several people at a local restaurant.  Police recovered a  _high-stress chemistry lab_ at the scene.

Comment: I know it's not quite the same thing, but I've got the phrase "Voltage-Calmed" running through my head.

Answer (score 9):

### [Tetrahydrocannabinol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahydrocannabinol)

THC is the main component of cannabis. It’s easily delivered in vaporised form and its effects are felt very quickly. These include relaxation, euphoria, stress and pain relief, increased appreciation of music, art and interestingly shaped clouds, and the munchies.

You prepare your victim with a spray of high-quality, concentrated ganja extract. Their strength is sapped and they fall to the floor, but honestly, they don’t care, because they’ve found somme *really interesting* patterns in the carpet. In fact, now that you’re closer, you can see they are pretty cool. Someone tells a joke and it’s, like, *really funny*. You remember you have some nut bars in your rations. Man, those are some *good* nut bars. You two bond over your shared appreciation of the Grateful Dead. You can’t remember why you wanted to attack anybody. Peace out, man.

Comment: This is a great answer! Drugs in the literal sense!

Answer (score 8):

**Nitrous Oxide**

> Nitrous oxide, commonly known as laughing gas or happy gas, is a colorless, non-flammable gas. This gas is used in medical and dental procedures as a sedative. It helps to relieve anxiety before the procedure and allow the patient to relax. ([WebMD](https://www.webmd.com/a-to-z-guides/what-to-know-about-laughing-gas))

Nitrous Oxide is a mild airborne sedative/anesthetic. It can be sprayed or delivered as a bomb similar to tear gas. As an airborne agent it's possible that the climate may push the gas back on the person delivering the blow. Proper preparation with a filtration mask can protect against most of these kinds of problems.

The gas gets its nickname because it makes people feel light headed, relaxed, happy, and giggly.

Most sedatives are not airborne. Most are liquids and must be delivered with...

**A Tranquilizer Dart**

While the dart is merely the method of delivering the sedative, I can imagine your culture developing a robust tradtion of concealed weapons. Like the cane swords of old and the CCW permits of today, your culture would find ways of carrying small amounts of sedatives in varying strengths should an opponent start winding up to a majest temper tantrum a bit faster than yourself.

Comment: Great answer! I confess I didn't think about laughing gas. I should have paid more attention in chemistry!

Answer (score 8):

### Kittens as Service Animals

Everyone has pet cats.
If anyone feels angry they can look down at their little furry companion and feel the fury melt away.

If someone has left their kitten at home (the monster!) then someone else can hold up theirs and those huge round eyes will do their magic whether the angry person wants it to or not.

How can you stay mad with these eyes looking at you?

[image]

Comment: Lol, good answer. It wouldn't really apply to most bad people, but it would work great for a regular citizen.

Comment: Unless, of course, you're angry because the cat has just asked to be let in, five seconds after asking to be let out, for the tenth time that day.

Answer (score 3):

**Food.**

[image: hangry]

https://www.foxnews.com/food-drink/hangry-is-officially-a-word-in-the-oxford-english-dictionary

Your opponent is angry.  Probably he is hungry.  He is hangry.  I bet you are too.  Both of you grumpy gusses need to mitigate your anger.  The chemical I propose is pizza.  There is antagonism between you and so you will have the delivery person bring two pizzas so your adversary knows you did not put cat hair on his pizza (as you are known to do).  Each of you gets his own pizza.

You pay as a gesture of goodwill.  Your adversary does not think you tipped enough and so tips the delivery person some more.  You thought ahead and with the pizza you got your adversary some wings because you heard he likes wings.  You got yourself some cheeze bread.

You forgot to order drinks.  But you remember you have some sodas.  It turns out your adversary has 2 beers left also.  You two finish all the drinks.

When you are done both of you are both less angry.  Hardly angry at all.   Really more of a food coma because there is nothing left.  And it is pretty nice out still.  Maybe you can go outside and sit in the grass and talk thru your differences?